# hanging long shelves on a mobile home wall

Tags: drywall

I live in a 1988 Fleetwood manatee mobile home. I'm trying to hang long shelves 8ft long x 12inches, every anchor that I have tried to put in comes out. So how do I add this shelves on my old mobile home walls?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what anchors you've tried? Are we talking standard drywall anchors? Screw-ins? And are the walls drywall or a composite board?

Comment: Tip: do not use drywall anchors to support shelves. Shelving brackets should be secured directly to framing members. I do not know anything about mobile home construction so I cannot offer an actual answer to your question.

Comment: What kind of shelf do you want to attach to the wall? What will be the weight on it? What kind of bracing or brackets will be used to support the shelf?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile homes have vertical studs just like a wood frame house. These may be 2x3" x ~8 ft rather than 2x4" as in a fixed structure, but they will still support a shelf if done properly for the expected load on the shelf. The studs will be 16" apart or 24" apart.

You must locate the studs and attach the fasteners through the finished wall (paneling or drywall) into the studs. Also be sure you do not drill into an electrical wire in making holes for the fasteners.

An electronic stud finder is useful to locate the studs, but it does take practice to learn how to use these correctly. Some people use magnets to find the studs by finding the nails used to attach the interior finish wall panels to the studs. Some people can locate the studs by rapping on the wall with their knuckles.

**Addition**

Electrical boxes for receptacles or wall switches in houses are usually attached to the sides of studs so if you have a receptacle under where the shelf is to be, then there would be a stud on one side or the other of the receptacle. But in at least some mobile homes the receptacles are not attached to studs.  In any case once you find a stud by some means you would look for other studs 16" (center-to-center) away on both sides, but the distance between studs is not always 16" and some framing is 24" on centers.

Comment: I just did a room addition on a Fleetwood double wide. The exterior walls where 2x4 16"oc, but the electrical is not installed in a box mounted to the studs. They are sealed free floating electric outlets. So don't count on locating a stud by way of eletrical outlets. Nor should you in a stick built house as an old work box can be placed anywhere in a wall opening.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to hanging new shelves in any length is to use a stud finder and mark it with a straight edge. The size of the studs rather 2x3 or 2x4 or even 2x6s if it happens to me on an exterior wall of the MH does not matter as long as you locate the middle of the stud and if there are existing holes there, use a screw sleeve or a hack I have found where you break of half a toothpick and stick it in the hole and use a new screw to secure it.